# Absolute URL when calling wcf method using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, absolute-path

This is probably very simple, but i've been stuck for a while.

I have a user-control which is calling a method like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myabtags").tagit({
            tagSource: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags",
                    datatype: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{"prefix":"' + request.term + '"}',
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.GetTagsResult);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

However, this user control is used several places on my website. For instance at root, /Admin/ and several others.

I would want to do something like:

```
url: "~/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags"
```

How do you do that in jQuery ?

**Attemps**:

Putting slash in front, like

```
url: "/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags"
```

That doesn't work. I get a 404 error back: `http://localhost:16481/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags" (gives 404)`.

Instead it should be

```
http://localhost:16481/Client/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags"
```

Comment: Did you try with just url: "/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags",

Comment: Yes I tried :-) Gives me a 404 call (i'll update post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is always in the same location, use an absolute path (`"/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags"`). However, if you deploy the same codebase to multiple sites, which may have different root paths, I use this trick:

It works like this: I assume all JS scripts for my application are in a folder, such as `Scripts`. I then have a common JS file that has utilities, including a place to keep the absolute root URL and a method to make absolute URLs. Then I search for a script block with that src, and extract the root URL.

```
(function($)
{
    $.myapp = {};
    var $a = $.myapp;

    $.extend($a, {
        rootUrl: '',
        makeAbsoluteRootPath: function(path) {
            return path.replace('~/', $a.rootPath);
        }
    });

    var tag = $('script[src*="scripts"]').first();
    if (tag.length > 0) {
        var url = tag.attr('src').replace(/\/?(scripts).+$/i, '/');
        $a.rootPath = url;

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Now you can resolve the absolute root path dynamically:

```
url: $.myapp.makeAbsoluteRootPath("~/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/tRMSj/

Answer (score 1):

To make the path relative to the root of the website client-side, prepend a slash:

```
url: "/Client/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/GetTags"
```

Note - if `Client` is the virtual directory / application in IIS express, and when it is installed it won't have the `Client` bit, you will need to change it.